# I want to make an icon appear over one that deletes after clicking it

Tags: jquery, click, icons

http://www.foundersfund.com/
notice on this page that when you click the top right menu button, an ex 
button appears, from which you can click that and put the menu back up, this 
is what I want, but this is what my webpage is doing, try it out: file:///Users/MacbookPro2011/Desktop/RedWeave/JQuery/redweave.html

```
here is my code: 

<body>

<div id="mainBar">

<div id="menuButton">

<div id="exButton"></div>

</div>

</div>

<script text="type/javascript">

$("#menuButton").click(function() {

$("#mainBar").animate({ height:"300px" },500);

$("#menuButton").animate({ height:"0px", width:"0px"},5);

$("#exButton").animate({ height:"30px", width:"30px"},5);

});

$("#exButton").click(function() {

$("#mainBar").animate({ height:"100px" },500);

$("#menuButton").animate({ height:"30px", width:"30px"},5);

$("#exButton").animate({ height:"0px", width:"0px"},5);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet I've created, I think it would be easier for you to go on from here by yourself.

```js
$("#menuButton").click(function() {
  $("#menuButton").toggleClass("close");
  $(".main-menu").toggleClass("expanded");
  if ($("#mainBar").hasClass("collapsed")) {
    $("#mainBar").animate({
      "height": "400px"
    }, function() {
      $("#mainBar").removeClass("collapsed");
    });
  } else {
    $("#mainBar").animate({
      "height": "80px"
    }, function() {
      $("#mainBar").addClass("collapsed");
    });

  }

});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 #menuButton {
  background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 24px;
}
#menuButton.close {
  background: url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/18_Close-128.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#mainBar {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  position: relative;
}
#mainBar.collapsed {
  height: 80px;
}
.menu-header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.main-menu {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 330px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.main-menu.expanded {
  display: table-cell;
}
ul.main-menu li>a {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainBar" class="collapsed">
  <div id="menuButton"></div>
  <div class="menu-header">
    <ul class="main-menu" style="">
      <li><a href="#">Manifesto</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```